# mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php, appinventor

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
**<?php
$id = @$_POST['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = $id ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problema al insertar".mysqli_error());
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
$json[] = $rs;
echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>**
```

El error que me aparece es:
**Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqlcrud2\desc.php on line 10
Problema al insertar**

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que pasarle como parámetro el link de conexión (donde figura entre otros, la información sobre el error).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problema al insertar".mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: gracias! lo corregi y ahora me aparece esto: Problema al insertarYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 .